# Cannot update Template in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am connected to AWS via aws-cli and I want to update the HTML of one of my SES Templates. I already escaped quotes. Right now am getting the next error:

```
bash: !DOCTYPE: event not found
```

That is when I try to run the next command:

```
aws ses update-template --template-name my-template --template '{"TemplateName":"my-template","SubjectPart":"Welcome to system!","TextPart":"Invitation to login to system\n\nHi {{first-name}}. {{inviter}} wants to invite you to system. Follow the link below to continue.\n\n{{reset-password-link}}\n\nIf you're not interested, you can safely ignore this email.","HtmlPart":"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\">\n<head>\n<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" />\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n<title>Actionable emails e.g. reset password</title>\n\n\n<style type=\"text/css\">\nimg {\nmax-width: 100%;\n}\nbody {\n-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em;\n}\nbody {\nbackground-color: #f6f6f6;\n}\n@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {\n  body {\n    padding: 0 !important;\n  }\n  h1 {\n    font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;\n  }\n  h2 {\n    font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;\n  }\n  h3 {\n    font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;\n  }\n  h4 {\n    font-weight: 800 !important; margin: 20px 0 5px !important;\n  }\n  h1 {\n    font-size: 22px !important;\n  }\n  h2 {\n    font-size: 18px !important;\n  }\n  h3 {\n    font-size: 16px !important;\n  }\n  .container {\n    padding: 0 !important; width: 100% !important;\n  }\n  .content {\n    padding: 0 !important;\n  }\n  .content-wrap {\n    padding: 10px !important;\n  }\n  .invoice {\n    width: 100% !important;\n  }\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n\n<body itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/EmailMessage\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; width: 100% !important; height: 100%; line-height: 1.6em; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;\" bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\">\n\n<table class=\"body-wrap\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; background-color: #f6f6f6; margin: 0;\" bgcolor=\"#f6f6f6\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;\" valign=\"top\"></td>\n\t\t<td class=\"container\" width=\"600\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; display: block !important; max-width: 600px !important; clear: both !important; margin: 0 auto;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t<div class=\"content\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; max-width: 600px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px;\">\n\t\t\t\t<table class=\"main\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" itemprop=\"action\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/ConfirmAction\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #fff; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;\" bgcolor=\"#fff\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-wrap\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 20px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<meta itemprop=\"name\" content=\"Confirm Email\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\" /><table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-block\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPassword reset request.\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-block\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHi {{first-name}}. {{inviter}} wants to invites you to system. Click on the link below to set up your password check out our platform.\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-block\" itemprop=\"handler\" itemscope itemtype=\"http://schema.org/HttpActionHandler\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;\" valign=\"top\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"{{reset-password-link}}\" class=\"btn-primary\" itemprop=\"url\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #348eda; margin: 0; border-color: #348eda; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;\">Set Password</a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"content-block\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;\" valign=\"top\">\n                  If you're not interested, you can safely ignore this email.\n                </td>\n              </tr></table></td>\n\t\t\t\t\t</tr></table><div class=\"footer\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; width: 100%; clear: both; color: #999; margin: 0; padding: 20px;\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<table width=\"100%\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><tr style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;\"><td class=\"aligncenter content-block\" style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: top; color: #999; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">from my Company</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr></table></div></div>\n\t\t</td>\n\t\t<td style=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0;\" valign=\"top\"></td>\n\t</tr></table></body>\n</html>\n"}'
```

I have been checking the JSON contecnt but I don't know now where it's failing

Comment: It's probably the `<` in `<!DOCTYPE` that is causing the problem. Try escaping that.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi! and how can I scape than symbol? with  \ ?

Comment: Try using: `\<`

Comment: @JohnRotensteinI still get the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than attempting to do this via the AWS CLI, which is having difficulties with special characters, you might want to try it via a programming language.

For example, here's some Python code:

```py
import boto3

ses_client = boto3.client('ses')

ses_client.update_template(
    Template={
        'TemplateName': 'my-template',
        'SubjectPart': 'Welcome to system!',
        'TextPart': """Invitation to login to system\n\nHi {{first-name}}. {{inviter}} wants to invite you to system. Follow the link below to continue.\n\n{{reset-password-link}}\n\nIf you're not interested, you can safely ignore this email.""",
        'HtmlPart': """html part goes here"""
    }
)
```

When providing the `HtmlPart`, you won't need to escape characters because they are in the block surrounded by `"""` quotes.